# how to add arrow key control for dropdown list ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

below code works fine, this drop down list receives data from php serer side code,

but i need to select items from drop down list using arrow keys,
also need to set value on input field when i select item using arrow keys.
tried several methods, need some help.

here are the code,

```
<div class="frmSearch">
    <input type="text" id="search-box" placeholder="Country Name" />
    <div id="suggesstion-box"></div>
</div>


// AJAX call for autocomplete 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search-box").keyup(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "readCountry.php",
        data:'keyword='+$(this).val(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#search-box").css("background","#FFF url(LoaderIcon.gif) no-repeat 165px");
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#suggesstion-box").show();
            $("#suggesstion-box").html(data);
            $("#search-box").css("background","#FFF");
        }
        });
    });
});
//To select country name
function selectCountry(val) {
$("#search-box").val(val);
$("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}



<?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
if(!empty($_POST["keyword"])) {
$query ="SELECT * FROM country WHERE country_name like '" . $_POST["keyword"] . "%' ORDER BY country_name LIMIT 0,6";
$result = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
if(!empty($result)) {
?>
<ul id="country-list">
<?php
foreach($result as $country) {
?>
<li onClick="selectCountry('<?php echo $country["country_name"]; ?>');"><?php echo $country["country_name"]; ?></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
<?php } } ?>
```

Comment: tried many methods? I don't see any here...

Comment: i didn't add here, do you have any suggestions

Comment: Please be aware that your database query is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use mysql_real_escape_string or prepared queries and check out https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp